# Disconnectedness of closed intervals in Sorgenfrey's line

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, sorgenfrey-line

In order to prove Sorgenfrey's line is totally disconnected I took the long road and proved every type of subset except singletones (intervals and rays) is disconnected. Everyone except for closed intervals were easy. I can't seem to prove that a closed interval $[a,b]$, for $a<b \in \Bbb{R}$, is disconnected. That is, I can't find two non-empty open sets (again - under the lower limit topology) whose disjoint union is equal to $[a,b]$.

Any hints?

Comment: Given any set $A$ with at least two points $a<b$ note that $(-\infty,b)\cap A$ and $[b,\infty)\cap A$ provides a clopen partition of $A$. Note $(-\infty,b)=\cup_{c<b}[c,b)=\cup_{c<a}[c,b)$, and $a\in(-\infty,b)$.

Comment: You do not want to find two  open subsets of the Sorgenfrey line $S$ whose union is $[a,b]$, and you can't because $[a,b]$ is not open in $S.$ What you want is two disjoint open non-empty subsets of the  $sub$-$space$  $[a,b]$ whose union is $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $[a,b]=[a,b)\cup\{b\}$ and $[a,b)$ and $\{b\}$ are open disjoint subsets of $[a,b]$, you're done. Note that $\{b\}$ is an open subset of $[a,b]$ because $\{b\}=[a,b]\cap[b,b+1)$.

Comment: Why is this singleton an open set? It's a finite intersection of an open set with a closed one and not of two open sets... Isn't it?

Comment: I **explained** why it is an open set. It's because it is the intersection of $[b,b+1)$ (an open set) with $[a,b]$.

Comment: Yeah I got it, but an open set is either a finite intersection of open sets or an arbitrary union of open sets - here you have neither. You have an intersection of an open set with the closed set $[a,b]$

Comment: Do you know the meaning of induced topology? Don't you know that an open subset of $[a,b]$ is any set of the form $A\cap[a,b]$ where $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$. Otherwise, how do *you* define an open subset of $[a,b]$?

Comment: I know what the induced topology is - I just thought that we are still in the context of the lower limit topology on $\Bbb{R}$. Why are we suddenly dealing with the induced topology on $[a,b]$ and $[a,b]$ as our new space (new context)?

Comment: @Friedman Aren't you trying to prove that $[a,b]$ is disconnected? Well, what that means is that you can express $[a,b]$ as the union of two open subsets of $[a,b]$ which are disjoint and non-empty. And, in this context, “open” means that it's open with respect to the induced topology.

Comment: Thanks, so my problem was with connectedness definition... I didn't realize we change contexts when dealing with subset of the original space (so that opennes is now with respect to the induced topology).

Answer (score 2):

All sets of the form $[a,b)$ are clopen (open and closed at the same time) and as these form a base for the topology, $\Bbb S$ is zero-dimensional topologically and Hausdorff, which implies that it is totally disconnected: no subset larger than a singleton is connected.